# Multiple unrelated in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I am using iReport with JasperReports.  I want to include multiple subreports that have unrelated sql queries.  I would like to be able to put these all on one report.
   The problem I am facing is that when I leave the master report sql query empty, none of my subreports have any data.  There isn't really anything that the master report sends to the subreports since they are unrelated.  Basically how do you throw multiple unrelated reports together into one report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `Detail Band` to show, you will need to fill the main report query, even if its just a dummy query, like say:

```
SELECT 'a' FROM DUMMY
```

This will make the Detail band appear, and with it all the sub reports.

Otherwise, if you don't want to use the Detail Band, you have the option to view the other bands without using a query. From `Edit` menu, choose `Report Properties`, under `More...` tab, set the flag `When no data` to `All Sections, no detail`